# Finding all 1 digit and 2 digits numbers in a larger number using regex

Tags: php, regex

I want to match all 1 digit and 2 digit numbers using regex.

Subject string: `'12345'`

Expected match: `1,2,3,4,5,12,23,34,45`

I'm trying: `\d(\d)?` but as result i get `12,2,34,3,5`

Comment: Why is all context missing? Could the string be: `'123abc456'`? Or only numbers? Why would you want to do this?

Comment: You'll have to run the regex pattern more than once because the engine doesn't go back to the beginning. Once 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 are matched it will not start off again from the beginning. You'll have to run one with `\d` then a second go with `\d{2}` but in this second run you'll match 12 and 34 and not 45. For the 3rd run, you'll have to use `(?<=\d)\d{2}` so that it starts of with a shift of one digit, in order to match 23 and 45.

Comment: See https://3v4l.org/0VfVB, `preg_match_all('~(?=((\d)\d?))~', $s, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER)` and a bit of post-processing will help.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, thank you very much, exactly what i was looking for.
I wondered if I can do that in a sigle regex request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
$s = "12345";
$res = [];
if (preg_match_all('~(?=((\d)\d?))~', $s, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    $single = []; $double = [];
    foreach ($m as $v) {
        if ($v[1] != $v[2]) {
            array_push($single, $v[2]);
            array_push($double, $v[1]);
        } else {
            array_push($single, $v[1]);
        }
    }
    $res = array_merge($single, $double);
    print_r( $res );
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/0VfVB). Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 12
    [6] => 23
    [7] => 34
    [8] => 45
)
```

**NOTES**:

- `(?=((\d)\d?))` - a regex that captures into Group 1 two or one digits, and into Group 2 the first digit of the previous sequence
- `PREG_SET_ORDER` groups the captures into the same parts of the match array
- If the match is a single digit, the `$double` array is not modified
- The final array is a combination of single digit array + double digit array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure this can be done with regex as it will match 2 OR 1, then move on through the string.

So if it finds "12" at position 0, it will move to position 1 and find "2".

But if it finds "1" at position 0, it will move to position 1 and find "2" and never see "12".

I'm not sure if what it finds is random or not.

You can acheieve this with some PHP code though.

Loop through the characters and at each position ask...

Is this character numeric? If yes add to array.

Is this character and the next character numeric? If yes, concat both and add to array.

Then move to next position.

```php
<?php

$string = '12345f67';
$chars = str_split($string);
$length = count($chars);
$numbers = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    if (is_numeric($chars[$i])) {
        $numbers[] = (int) $chars[$i];
        
        if ($i < ($length - 1) && is_numeric($chars[$i + 1])) {
            $numbers[] = (int) ($chars[$i].$chars[$i+1]);
        }
    }
}


print_r($numbers);
```

Results below of above code....

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 23
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 34
    [6] => 4
    [7] => 45
    [8] => 5
    [9] => 6
    [10] => 67
    [11] => 7
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward solution:

```
$digits = '12345';
preg_match_all('/\d/', $digits, $single_digit_matches);
preg_match_all('/\d\d/', $digits, $two_digit_matches1);
preg_match_all('/\d\d/', substr($digits, 1), $two_digit_matches2);
$matches = array_merge($single_digit_matches[0], $two_digit_matches1[0], $two_digit_matches2[0]);
asort($matches);
print_r($matches);
```

The output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 12
    [7] => 23
    [6] => 34
    [8] => 45
)
```